# Should I create separate collection in firestore for separate type of users. Will it affect performance if I have huge collection of users

Tags: performance, google-cloud-firestore

Should I create separate collection in firestore for separate type of users. Will it affect performance if I have huge collection of users.
For example we have lets say Users of Type A and Users of Type B.
Schema for Type A is different than Type B.

Will I get any benefit by keeping those users in different collection?

Answer (score 0):

Having a huge collection of users will not affect performance by itself, but I can think of some cases in which, depending on the usage, it may be helpful to split a collection into several.

For example, if your app has to perform full table scans often for the users collection, splitting the collection may reduce overall query latency and decrease Firestore costs, which are based on the [number of document operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations:%7E:text=You%20are%20charged%20for%20each%20document%20read).